# Calling new Date(String s) produces result in different timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I am trying to display a date in javascript. I receive the date from backend like this: `2020-09-22T17:10:25Z` (from and Instant object in Java).

When I try to call `new Date("2020-09-22T17:10:25Z")` I get: `Tue Sep 22 2020 20:10:25 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`. The issue with this is that I am not in a `GMT+0300` timezone but rather `GMT+0200`.

When I try to call `new Date()` on the other hand I get `Thu Dec 08 2022 20:34:11 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)` which is my correct timezone.

My question is, why in the first case I get the `GMT+0300` and in the second case I get `GMT+0200`? The `Z` in the string I am trying to parse stands for `Zulu` or `zero hour offset`, so why does the 2 different approaches use different timezones?

Comment: Because on 2020-09-22 (which is the date you receiving) your timezone was in Summer time (GMT +3)

Comment: `new Date` does not produce different results. It's a date object representing as much as the `Instant` from your java backend - just a timestamp, no timezone attached. It's `.toString()` that uses your system timezone *for formatting only*. But if you don't want that, just use `.toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: Part of the confusion may be that often one might call `console.log` on the result.  Unfortunately, there's no standard that applies for how objects (including `Date`) are converted to strings when logged.  Some JS environments will use `Date.prototype.toString` and others will use `Date.prototype.toISOString`.  WhatWG controls the `console` spec, and ECMA controls the `Date` spec, but neither will cooperate to resolve this.  [I've tried](https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/132).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are in `GMT+2` in winter, but in summer (in September) you are in summer time which is `GMT+3`

Answer (score 0):

javascript's date() function works off of the time set on your local computer. if it is giving `GMT+3`, then your computer is set to `GMT+3`. check your system clock's configuration.

windows: https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=79027

mac: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp2996/mac

linux: https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-set-date-and-time-linux/